# Accessing class objects in different classes

Tags: class, swift2

There are a total of 3 classes in all.

1. In the first class, it will do all `init` to manage the strings.
2. In the second class, it creates an array of class objects for first class.
3. In the third class, it will access the data stored in the second class. (This is where I need to know.)

FirstClass.swift

```
class Person{
    var name : String
    var description : String

    init(name: String, description: String){
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
    }
```

SecondClass.swift

```
class StoreData: UIViewController {

    var personList = [Person]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.personList.append(Person(name: "John", description: "123"))
        self.personList.append(Person(name: "Mary", description: "456"))
    }
```

ThirdClass.swift

So in this class, I need to access the data that is stored in SecondClass.swift. Say I wat to store in a string array of names. I want to extract where `var names = personList[0].name` How do I do so?

Comment: You code won't work. `StoreData` has `override func viewDidLoad()` but is is not inherited from `UIViewController`.

Comment: added UIViewController.

Comment: What is your ThirdClass swift? Why do you make `StoredData` class like `UIViewController`? You use `MVC`? Can you just pass the reference of StoredData to your third class?

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to swift. What is MVC? Yes, I can pass reference. I do not need to amend anything. I just need to grab data inside the array object to use on my ThirdClass.swift

Comment: Show code of your ThirdClass.swift

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in your case to make it work is like this:

```
class StoreData: UIViewController {
    static var sharedData = StoreData()
    var personList = [Person]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.personList.append(Person(name: "John", description: "123"))
        self.personList.append(Person(name: "Mary", description: "456"))
    }
}

class ThirdClass {

    func someFunc() {
        let person1 = StoreData.sharedData.personList[0]
        print(person1)
    }
}
```

But it's not the best way, but you can't explain what you need. Hopes you understand, that this code makes singleton from `StoreData`. And it will work for you task.